# Set environment variable to function result

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm a bit of a noob to batch programming. I've got this very small and simple code to do some stuff with `Tuppers` self-referential formula:

```
java -jar Tuppers.jar --read-image <img file you want to read>
```

I have the image file in a folder called `Read`. So I use this command line:

```
java -jar Tuppers.jar --read-image Read\*
```

since I will only have one file at a time in that folder.

I wanna set a variable `num` to the result of the function and then `echo` it out, but if I use

```
set /p num = java -jar Tuppers.jar --read-image Read\*
```

then its just gonna set the variable to the command line.

Comment: If you are talking about the Windows command line and Windows batch files: that has **nothing** to do with "DOS programming". (MS-)DOS is dead and forgotten.

Comment: Yeah, i certainly am a noob, i dont even know what its called

Comment: What is the output of `java -jar Tuppers.jar --read-image Read\*`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting a variable from an executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768347/setting-a-variable-from-an-executable)

Comment: it says: java -jar Tuppers.jar --read-image Read\*

Comment: I don't think you understand what I asked. What does `java -jar Tuppers.jar --read-image Read\*` print to the screen?

Answer (score 0):

```
For /f "delims=" %A in ('java -jar Tuppers.jar --read-image Read\*') do echo %A
```

See `for /?` and use `%%A` in a batch file and `%A` when typing.

Comment: Yeah, it looks good, at least the right idea, putting the code which's result i need in the viable into a snippet, ill try it when i get home :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

The standard output of any Windows command line program can be picked up in various ways.

Redirection to a file via > and >>

Piping to another command via |

And in your case picked up as a line of output.  Try this from the command line:
`for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('java -jar Tuppers.jar --read-image Read\*') do set myvar=%i`

After that myvar, which you can check the contents of via "echo %myvar%", will contain the last line output from the java command.

Note that for this to work your java Tuppers.jar needs to print the number you want to standard output.

Comment: Yeah seems a lot the same as what Trigger told me, in this case i can aswell just start off echoing it out since thats my goal anyway, thanks for the help :)